# how to quickly insert 1 million data into mysql using rust

Tags: rust, large-files

I'm still learning rust, to process data I find rust runs very fast, but when try to inserting data into mysql I haven't found a way to do it quickly (compared to me doing it in python in under 1 minutes, rust need 15+ minutes).

I'm using rust library "mysql" to insert data into db with code:

```
use mysql::*;

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Eq)]
struct ListPhone {
    phone_no: String,
}

fn insert_mysql(data: Vec<ListPhone>) -> () {
    let url = "mysql://user:pass@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3306/learn";

    let pool = mysql::Pool::new(url);

    let mut conn = pool.expect("error pool conn").get_conn();
    let res = conn.expect("error running").exec_batch(
        r"INSERT INTO listPhone (phone_no)
          VALUES (:phone_no)",
        data.into_iter().map(|p| {
            params! {
                "phone_no" => p.phone_no,
            }
        }),
    );
    println!("done")
}
```

Has anyone explored inserting large datasets into mysql using rust language quickly (batch, row), or is there any library that can help?

Edit :
when I log all the queries I can see the difference between the queries generated in python and my rust script. in python the script will be like this:

> insert into listPhone (phone_no) values (1),(2),(3)... all the data

and then executing it one statement

, but in rust it will generate :

> "insert into listPhone (phone_no) values (1)",

> "insert into listPhone (phone_no) values (2)",

> "insert into listPhone (phone_no) values (3)",
> ... the rest of the data

and execute for each statement.

is there a way to convert the resulting statement into a single statement?

edit 2:

i tried this solution in idiomatic way, i don't know about efficiency but this solution can do it with faster time compared to the python script i have. but I still hope someone has a more elegant solution.

```
fn insert_mysql_batch_experiment(data: Vec<ListPhone>) -> () {
     let mut vec = Vec::new();
    let url = env::var("DATABASE_URL").expect("load env failed");
    let pool = mysql::Pool::new(&*url).expect("error pool conn");
    let mut conn = pool.get_conn().expect("error conn");

    for x in data.iter() {
        vec.push(x.phone_no.clone());
    }
    let hasil = vec.join("'),('");
    let final_str = [
        "INSERT INTO listPhone (phone_no) VALUES ",
        "('",
        &hasil,
        "')",
    ]
    .join("");

    {
        let query_result = conn.query_iter(final_str);
        query_result.expect("error inserting data");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I can see, if you don't execute the inserts in a transaction, `exec_batch` will execute each statement independently, without a transaction. Executing all inserts in the same transaction should give you a significant speed-up:

```rust
let pool = mysql::Pool::new(url).expect("error pool conn");
let mut conn = pool.get_conn().expect("error conn");
let mut trans = conn
    .start_transaction(TxOpts::default())
    .expect("error trans");
let res = trans.exec_batch(
    r"INSERT INTO listPhone (phone_no)
      VALUES (:phone_no)",
    data.into_iter().map(|p| {
        params! {
            "phone_no" => p.phone_no,
        }
    }),
);
res.expect("error batching");
trans.commit().expect("error commit");
```

Note however that you may run into concurrent modification exceptions if any of the rows touched by this transaction is modified by any other client, so splitting the `exec_batch` into smaller batches with `data.chunks(1234)` and adding commits and retrys after each batch may be necessary.

Another approach I've used to speed up inserts for postgres is to prepare (e.g.) 14 statements like `INSERT INTO … VALUES (row1), (row2), …` for 1, 2, 4, 8, …, 8192 rows and then inserting your rows in chunks, using whatever the largest chunk is that fits the remaining data. I can't test this code right now, but it should look something like this:

```rust
let preps = (0..13)
    .map(|i| {
        let mut query = "INSERT INTO listPhone (phone_no) VALUES (?)".to_owned();
        for _ in 1..(1 << i) {
            query.push_str(",(?)");
        }
        trans.prep(query)
    })
    .collect::<Result<Vec<_>, _>>()
    .expect("prepare");
let mut data = &data[..];
while !data.is_empty() {
    let prep = preps
        .iter()
        .rfind(|s| s.params().len() <= data.len())
        .unwrap();
    let chunk = data[..prep.params.len()]
        .iter()
        .map(|p| &p.phone_no)
        .collect::<Vec<_>>();
    trans.exec_iter(prep, chunk).expect("insert");
    data = &data[prep.params().len()..];
}
```

Whether this yields any further speed-up with mysql is unknown to me.

Comment: thanks for your reply, this code speeds up the process, but still can't keep up with pandas+sql alchemy speed in python. and I find it strange, maybe you have a suggestion library I can try for mysql?

Comment: Sorry, I'm no MySQL performance alchemist, so I don't know what happens differently in your python code. You could try playing with the isolation level in the `TxOpts`. But my next step would be to [log all queries](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/62129/how-to-log-all-mysql-queries-into-log-file) and find out what sqlalchemy is actually doing

Comment: i have edited the question after adding the log results, is there a way to convert the resulting query into a single statement in rust?

Comment: One thing I would find more "elegant" is to not throw the phone numbers into the query by value but use a prepared statement. I've also added a code sketch for the second idea I suggested.

Comment: Oh yeah: You could also try to split your `data` into a few chunks and [spawn](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/thread/fn.scope.html) a few threads.

Comment: your second suggestion is fast, sometimes faster than my solution. but since they differ only slightly in time, it's hard to be absolutely sure.
but this is a more "elegant" written solution than mine, thanks for all the answers.

Answer (score 1):

Using diesel (ORM like SQLAlchemy), you can insert multiple rows at once. It may generate raw SQL like "insert into listPhone (phone_no) values (1),(2),(3)".

```
    let new_post = vec![
        NewPost { title: "title1",  body:  "body1"},
        NewPost { title: "title2",  body:  "body2"},
        NewPost { title: "title3",  body:  "body3"},
        NewPost { title: "title4",  body:  "body4"},
    ];
    
    diesel::insert_into(posts::table)
        .values(&new_post)
        .get_result(conn)
        .expect("Error saving new post")
```

Comment: i tried this solution, it works as expected when using small portion of data. but when i use the full 1Mil data it shows "'main' thread panicked on 'Error saving new post: DatabaseError(__Unknown, "The prepared statement contains too many placeholders")',". so I think it works and is simpler, but can be used depending on the use case. thanks for the idea